# How to access custom subdirectories in helpers (ruby on rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper, subdirectory

Ruby on Rails:
Is there any way to access subdirectories in helpers directory?

I mean:

/app/helpers/"subdir"/"foo.rb"

So I'd like to access methods and constants in foo.rb...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails includes all helpers by default, including those in subdirectories.

If your configuration requires controllers to include their own helpers, placing this in a controller:

```
helper "subdir/foo"
```

will include `/app/helpers/subdir/foo_helper.rb`, whose methods will be available to that controller's views.

Comment: I'm using RubyMine and its intellisense doesn't show the helper and the methods... :( Thanks for the answer!

Comment: what is the preferred way to write a unit test for a helper in a subdirectory? I'm having problems getting the helper included correctly in test file (and having the methods available to test)